# Trimstart and TrimEnd not working as wanted

Tags: c#

I am testing to cut the strings via C#, but I am not getting the results correctly.
It is still showing the full text exactString.

```
String exactString = ABC@@^^@@DEF
char[] Delimiter = { '@', '@', '^', '^', '@', '@' };
string getText1 = exactString.TrimEnd(Delimiter);
string getText2 = exactString.TrimStart(Delimiter);
MessageBox.Show(getText1);
MessageBox.Show(getText2);
```

OUTPUT:

`ABC@@^^@@DEF` for both getText1 and getText2.

Correct OUTPUT should be
ABC for getText1 and DEF for getText2.

How do I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: what is your logic of trimming here with a char array???

Comment: HiHi, I should use the split string method as Heinzi mentioned... Missed off my head... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to **split** your string, not **trim** it. Thus, the correct method to use is [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
String exactString = "ABC@@^^@@DEF";
var result = exactString.Split(new string[] {"@@^^@@"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(result[0]);  // outputs ABC
Console.WriteLine(result[1]);  // outputs DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx), not Trim.

```
char[] Delimiter = { '@', '^' };
string getText1 = exactString.Replace(Delimiter,'');
```

Trim only removes the characters at the beginning, Replace looks through the whole string.

You can split strings up in 2 pieces using the (conveniently named) [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

```
char[] Delimiter = { '@', '^' };
string[] text = exactString.Split(Delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//text[0] = "ABC", text[1] = "DEF
```

Comment: I used split new string instead... :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
String exactString = "ABC@@^^@@DEF";
string[] splits = exactString.Split(new string[]{"@@^^@@"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
string getText1 = splits[0];
string getText2 = splits[1];
MessageBox.Show(getText1);
MessageBox.Show(getText2);
```